# summer-note not works in bootstrap Modal(Modal content loads from a view)

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I am working on a Laravel project. and I have a Modal for adding a new product, the modal content loads from a view (Product Form is in a separated view. when click on "Add Product" button, the product form loads inside the modal).

now I'm going to use summer-note in description textarea, but it does not work.

note: CSS and Javascript links are correct. in the normal view, it work fine.

Here are HTML codes

`<textarea class="form-control" name="description" id="summernote" rows="4"></textarea>`

and I called this function inside the "Add Product" view.

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#summernote').summernote();
        });
```

Comment: I think it should be called inside the `<div>` not in `<textarea>`

Comment: @KamleshBhurke I don't think so. because I checked it in Normal view, it works with both inside `<div>`  and  `<textarea>`

Comment: can you provide a codepen? I would be happy to work on it then. Thank you!